# Program to log when files are written to a folder

Tags: logging, malware

One of our companies server seems to have fallen victim to a php backdoor attack.  I've managed to located and close several holes, but one seems to persist that is writing a php/webshell backdoor into our C:/windows/temp.

Microsoft Security Essentials seems to do a good job of detecting this threat and removing it before it can execute but the problem is I need to view the file security properties to see which app pool is creating these files (we have about 16 different sites on this server).

Does anyone know of a program/way that I can to monitor file writes to C:/windows/temp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First:

You should restore from a known good backup. At the very least, scan the server offline using a rescue CD of some kind. With that out of the way...

### Next:

Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to see deeply into process and file activity. You can also [use security policy to audit filesystem access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399). However, since the server is compromised, I wouldn't trust anything that it tells me.

[image: Nuke it from orbit!]
(Click the picture! You'll like it!)

Answer (score 1):

For the one-off answer, Microsoft Sysinternals [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) will watch any file activity that you desire and a bit more.